# SSRS Is it possible to build custom components

Tags: reporting-services

Is it possible to build custom components and use them in SSRS reports ?

I am working on a project and they have a couple graphics that I am not sure I can reproduce in native ssrs.

Take the bubble chart for instance - D3 can do this easily and it is on of their first examples.
It would be great if i could build a component that ran an .aspx page (or something) and rendered the resulting html as hopefully html,  but at least as a jpeg.

[image: D3 ish Bubble Chart]

This chunky chart seems simple enough that I could probably be just a new native chart type in SSRS. It would be great if that is an option.

[image: Chunky Square Chart]

Inspecting the report output page, i see that all images on a page are rendered as a single image. 
[image: composite image rendered by ssrs as a single image]

which is referenced by a link like this.  Has anyone tried to manipulate this link and add another image to this?

```
http://localhost/ReportServer/Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd?ExecutionID=0qtc0huclnvpir55n2hkwg55&Culture=1033&CultureOverrides=False&UICulture=9&UICultureOverrides=False&ReportStack=1&ControlID=a7b79ccaf78946e2aacde736345027a7&OpType=ReportImage&IterationId=8e6ebf108aa145a98d2265779187e2cf&StreamID=IMGCON_1_0
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it is possible.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/custom-report-items/creating-a-custom-report-item-run-time-component?view=sql-server-ver15

It references the [SQL Server Rpering SErvices Product Samples](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=177889) multiple times.This 
takes you to codeplex.com which is often flagged by CHROME as dangerous. I am not able to find the sample code.

Answer (score 0):

It is a bit late but just in case someone else has this problem the only suite of supported custom report items for SSRS is Nevron’s SSRS Vision, which targets specifically SSRS data visualization (charts, gauges, barcodes, etc.).:
https://www.nevron.com/products-reporting-services-vision

Disclosure: I work for Nevron.

Comment: Realize its probably not in your best interest, but what api do you use to develop those?  No longer at that client but we had need to develop some special components and I could not make it happen.  Had to do the walk of shame...